# Creating a logarithmic spaced array in IDL

Tags: arrays, idl

I was looking for a way to generate a logarithmic spaced array in IDL.
From the L3 Harris Geospatial website I came across "arrgen" and was trying to use it for this purpose. However,

```
arrgen(1,215,/log)
```

returns the error: Variable is undefined: ARRGEN.

What would be the correct way to do it?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Start by defining your lower and upper bounds in which ever log-base you prefer.  I will use base $e$ for brevity sake.

```
lowe = ALOG(low[0])
uppe = ALOG(upp[0])
```

where `low` and `upp` are scalar, numerical values you, the user, define (e.g., 1 and 215 in your example).  Then construct an evenly spaced array of `n` elements, such as:

```
dinde = DINDGEN(n[0])*(uppe[0] - lowe[0])/(n[0] - 1L) + lowe[0]
```

where `n` is a scalar integer.  Now convert back to linear space to get:

```
dind = EXP(dinde)
```

This will be a logarithmically spaced array.  If you want to use base-10 log, then substitute `ALOG` for `ALOG10`.  If you need another base, then you can use the logarithmic change of base rule given by:

log<sub>b</sub> x = log<sub>c</sub> x / log<sub>c</sub> b